# why does page keep reloading in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm making a small code that is a calculator. I'm finding it reloads every time i press submit. Not sure why this happens but it seems to only happen because of the submit() function.

This is my code for Javascript:

```
$(function() {
    $('#Try').submit(function() {
        var calc1 = document.getElementById("calculator").value;
        var calc2 = document.getElementById("calculator2").value;
        var select = document.getElementById("options");
        var option = select.options[select.selectedIndex].text;

        if (calc1 <= 0 || calc2 <= 0){
            if (calc2 == 0 && option == '%' || calc2 == 0 && option == '/') {
                alert("It's Over 9000")
                console.log("It's Over 9000")
            } else {
                alert("Error :(")
                console.log("Error :(")
            }
        } 
        else {
            var calculated = eval(calc1 + option + calc2);
            console.log("The answer is " + calculated);
            alert("The answer is " + calculated);
        }
    });
    const doom = setInterval(UseMe, 30000);

    function UseMe() {
        let text = "Please, use me...";
        alert(text);
    }
});
```

and here is the code for HTML:

```
<html>
    <head><title>Calculator</title></head>
    <header>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="calc.css">
        <script src='jquery-3.6.1.min.js'></script>
    </header>
    <body>
        <center>
            <table>
                <form>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="text" id="calculator" name="calc"></td>
                        <td><select id="options">
                            <option value="add ">+</option>
                            <option value="sub">-</option>
                            <option value="Times">*</option>
                            <option value="divide">/</option>
                            <option value="percent">%</option>
                        </select></td>
                        <td><input type="text" id="calculator2" name="calc"></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="submit" value="Try Me" id="Try"><br></td>
                    </tr>
                </form>
            </table>
        </center>
    </body>
    <script src="calc.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: that's what submitting a form does - load a new page

Comment: If you don't want to submit, then a) remove the `<form>` b) change `input type=submit` to `button type=button` and handle the button click event.   Or cancel the submit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prevent the default behaviour of the submit event.

Refer: https://api.jquery.com/submit/

```js
$('#Try').submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var calc1 = document.getElementById("calculator").value;
        var calc2 = document.getElementById("calculator2").value;
        var select = document.getElementById("options");
        var option = select.options[select.selectedIndex].text;

        if (calc1 <= 0 || calc2 <= 0){
            if (calc2 == 0 && option == '%' || calc2 == 0 && option == '/') {
                alert("It's Over 9000")
                console.log("It's Over 9000")
            } else {
                alert("Error :(")
                console.log("Error :(")
            }
        } 
        else {
            var calculated = eval(calc1 + option + calc2);
            console.log("The answer is " + calculated);
            alert("The answer is " + calculated);
        }
    });
```